Best way to get 80 wires down to 1? Is it even possible?
I'm new to working with power supplies but I'm planning on using two switching 24 V/40 A/960 W power supplies connected parallel. This power needs to connect to around 160 wires, 80 on each side of a big box. (40 positive and 40 negative wires).
I'm thinking of connecting the 80 wires through a terminal block, but is this safe? I was thinking also of twisting the wires together but I'm worried of interference because sensors and an ESP32 are going to be used near the LED lights.
Does anyone have any suggestions of how to wire it together.
Thanks!

Sketch up what your attempting to do. It's safe if you do it right.

Image is here: https://imgur.com/a/nHK9vTz. I meant to say 80 wires per side not 40

If you're worried about interference then you should specify what the potential interfering and interfered components are and how they are connected.

For one thing, your problem is cut in half if you use one power supply for 40 and one power supply for the other 40. Why do the power supplies need to be in  parallel?

And the esp32 isn't even in the drawing and how it's connected which is the most important part.

One power supply only provides 960W and I need about 1.5kW to power all the LEDS. I like the idea of only supply for 40 wires but how would i get 40 wires down to one? Like what connector or piece could do that.

Sorry the ESP32 will probably be connected to another source of power. I mentioned it before just because of my concerns with interference if I decide to transmit data wirelessly because the LEDS might interefere

How you connect the ESP32 to the rest of the circuit. Especially at the current level you are operating at.

Planning on powering the ESP32 from a wall socket, not the 960W supply.

That's great. But how does it interface with the LEDs? Why are you mentioning it?

please add the picture to the post, not in a comment  ... comments are not part of the question

Theoretically there is no problem connecting 80 loads to one source. You should not run those 2 supplies in parallel. It will probably work, but they are not designed to run that way, there may be problems; at 960W a fire might be one of them.
One caveat. Remember that your system is not just power supplies and loads. The bus bars or terminal blocks are part of the circuit. You have to make sure that each component the current passes through is within it's rating. If you do that, it should be safe.

All the LED's require 1.5 kW. That's 750 W worth of load per power supply. You have 40 LED loads per power supply. That's 18.75 W per branch (750 W/40). You're using 24V PS which implies your loads consume 1.28 A a piece (18.75 W/24V).
So, total consumption is 51.2 A (40 LEDs * 1.28 A).
Based on these numbers, this is one of several ways I would do it:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
One circuit is shown. But there are many configurations and the best will depend on your specific arrangement of parts. But the paradigm is the same: The sum of the currents of each branch ends up being the load for the branches up stream. Depending on how the distance, the wire sizes may need adjustment. You may also need a fuse for the power supply. But most modern switching power supplies, especially at that power level, have short circuit, foldback current limit, and over temperature built in. For easier wiring, you might want to cascade positive and negative circuits (alternate every other screw).
